# How to Autofill complicated formulas?

Tags: excel

I am trying to autofill my formula, but it is not recognizing the pattern.

My formula in the first cell is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(A1:D1)-CELL("Col",A1:D1)+0,2)=0)*(A1:D1))
```

In my second cell, I have:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(A1:D1)-CELL("Col",A1:D1)+0,2)=1)*(A1:D1))
```

Now for the third cell, I have:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(E1:H1)-CELL("Col",E1:H1)+0,2)=0)*(E1:H1))
```

And in the fourth cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(E1:H1)-CELL("Col",E1:H1)+0,2)=1)*(E1:H1))
```

So for each of these formula pairs, I have it sum A-D, E-H, and every set of 4 thereafter. My problem is that when I highlight those 4 cells and try to drag the formula across, it gets messed up and gives me the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(E1:H1)-CELL("Col",E1:H1)+0,2)=0)*(E1:H1))
```

Is there a way to autofill the formula so it follows the pattern I am trying to create?

Thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no, Autofill does not work that way.

You'll have to look at other functions (like `ROW()` or `COLUMN()` or others) to use the relative position of the formula as a way to offset the relative position of a cell you're trying to use in your outer formula.